How to remove a mongos router completely from a sharding cluster
After removing a mongos instance by force, I noticed that its information remains in the config.mongos collection. After a throughout search I found NO useful documentation explaining how to remove a mongos instance. The only option left is to manually remove that data like this:
mongos> use config
switched to db config
mongos> db.mongos.remove({ _id: "62-62-udp-1:6601" })
WriteResult({ "nRemoved" : 1 })
mongos>

Is there any command that I may use to remove a mongos safely?

Why would you like to do that? The data may not be correctly routed to that shard if mongos does not exist.

You should never make direct changes in config database unless explicitly advised by MongoDB.

@ray Thanks for leaving a comment, the reason is I need to completely remove a mongos from the sharding cluster.

Have a look at documentation:

Internal MongoDB Metadata
The config database is internal: applications and administrators
should not modify or depend upon its content in the course of normal
operation.
The mongos collection stores a document for each mongos instance
affiliated with the cluster. The cluster maintains this collection for
reporting purposes.

I would assume the host will disappear automatically after some time. The mongos hosts are nowhere configured in the database. Maybe, simply restart the cluster.

After removing a mongos, restarting both configServers and the other mongoses won't refresh data in config.mongos, "dirty" mongos remains there.

Why do care about the entries config.mongos at all? What's the reason to remove them?
